# How to remove noise between raspberry pi PWM0 and SIM800L mic pin?

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, low-pass, high-pass-filter

In my project SIM800L module(GSM Module) is interfaced with raspberry pi zero. Whenever user call Pi zero play an audio so that user can hear it. To send audio signal from pi zero to SIM800L, PWM0 pin is connected to MICP pin of SIM800L. Please check below image for connection information:

[image]

Here When PI zero detect incoming call, It's start playing audio, So PWM0 audio is sent to MICP of SIM800L. But when audio start i can hear noise in that call but once audio start playing noise gradually stop. So every time i call, for few second i can hear noise and then after audio noise stop gradually.

I don't have any idea why this noise is generated and how to remove this noise.

I am following below tutorial for reference: https://othermod.com/raspberry-pi-zero-audio-circuit/

If anyone can help me with this, it will be good help for me.

Thanks

Comment: What spectrum? or how does it sound?  Can you see it on supply or ground??  There is a DC shift when PWM is enabled unless idle is 50%

Comment: There may be automatic gain control circuits in the GSM device, you may be overdriving the input (a lot possibly)  Also it may be supplying some electret mic FET drive voltage on that pin (not sure) and be unhappy (or delighted) about your resistor to ground without a capacitor first, check application circuits for ideas.